# Upgrading to Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I am trying upgrade my Rails 2.3.9 application to Rails 3 and I am facing problems one after the other. I used autocomplete plugin for Rails 2.3.9 and it works fine. But now in Rails 3.0 instead of displaying the text box it just displays the html that needs to be generated. Here is my html code that generates the autocomplete field

```
<table class="table_style">
<caption><b>Customer Details</b></caption>
<tr>
<td><label for="customer_investigator"><%= RB['investigator']%></label><label class="mandatory">*</label></td>
<td><%= text_field_with_auto_complete "customer", :investigator,  { :onblur=> "if(this.value=='') {this.value='last, first';this.style.color='#aaa';}",:onfocus=> "if(this.value=='last, first') {this.value='';this.style.color='#000';}"},{:skip_style => true, :url=>{:action=>'autocomplete_name'}, :with =>"'name='+element.value"} %></td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

Now this is how the generated html looks like

```
"<input id="customer_investigator" name="customer[investigator]" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value='last, first';this.style.color='#aaa';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='last, first') {this.value='';this.style.color='#000';}" size="30" type="text" /><div class="auto_complete" id="customer_investigator_auto_complete"></div><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var customer_investigator_auto_completer = new Ajax.Autocompleter('customer_investigator', 'customer_investigator_auto_complete', '/accessions/autocomplete_name', {callback:function(element, value) { return 'name='+element.value }})
//]]>
</script>"
```

The content looks fine to me. But the generated html starts with quotes and hence instead of displaying a text box it just displays the generated html on the form. It was working perfectly fine with Rails 2.3.9. Can someone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **raw** before your autocomplete code:

```
<%= raw(text_field_with_auto_complete "customer", :investigator,  { :onblur=> "if(this.value=='') {this.value='last, first';this.style.color='#aaa';}",:onfocus=> "if(this.value=='last, first') {this.value='';this.style.color='#000';}"},{:skip_style => true, :url=>{:action=>'autocomplete_name'}, :with =>"'name='+element.value"}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using the rails_upgrade gem to upgrade my apps from rails 2 to rails 3. https://github.com/jm/rails_upgrade

As you said your facing problems one after the other, this gem could probably help you during the upgrade process.